# Click on anchor blocks javascript until server response

Tags: javascript, download, progress

I have web-method which respond with xml file. This file compiles in runtime and it may take a long time. For user it looks like inresponsible server, so I want to show compilation progress indicator. The problem is, I can capture anchor onclick and start long-polling to update indicator, but since click on anchor means user leave page, browser does not execute any code assigned with setInterval. Only when server done his job and answered with Content-Disposition header, browser figures out it can allow code execution. But it obviously already useless. Is there a way to make non-blocking file download? My only mention is to create hidden iframe and redirect downloading to it, while parent window renders progress indicator, but maybe there is more elegant solution?

Comment: The iframe sounds ok to me. Used in many places

Comment: Well, ok. It's easy to implement and I don't see any alternative. Thanks.